# Where should I put filetype specific options for indentation?

Tags: vimrc, filetype, ftplugin, indent

At moment, mostly for random reasons, I have

```
$ cat ~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim 
set tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 expandtab shiftwidth=2 smarttab smartindent autoindent cinoptions=g2
```

and this

```
$ cat ~/.vim/ftplugin/cpp.vim 
let c_no_curly_error = 1
set tabstop=8 softtabstop=8 expandtab shiftwidth=8 smarttab smartindent autoindent cinoptions=g2
set mps+=<:>
```

where I've put `2`s and `8`s in the two files for debugging purpose.

Since `:echo &tabstop` gives `2` when I open a `*.cpp` file (and also when I open a `*.c` file, which is expected), I'm pretty sure I've put those files in the wrong place or, at least, some lines of those files in the wrong file and wrong place.

In [Chapter 42 from *Learn Vimscript the Hard Way*](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/42.html) I read the following

> `~/.vim/indent/`
>
> Files in `~/.vim/indent/` are a lot like `ftplugin` files. They get loaded based on their names.
>
> `indent` files should set options related to indentation for their filetypes, and those options should be buffer-local.
>
> Yes, you could simply put this code in the `ftplugin` files, but it's better to separate it out so other Vim users will understand what you're doing. It's just a convention, but please be a considerate plugin author and follow it.

which tells me that, on the one hand, `~/.vim/indent/` would be a better place for filetype-specific Vim files containing `set tabstop=... ...`, and on the other hand tells me that `~/.vim/ftplugin/` isn't that bad.

Nonetheless, If I move those two files from `~/.vim/ftplugin/` to `~/.vim/indent/`, then `:echo &tabstop` gives the correct output of `8` for `*.cpp` files and `2` for `*.c` files.

This troubleshooting tells me that probably `~/.vim/ftplugin/` is a wrong place to put that setting, and `~/.vim/indent` is *maybe* the right place.

- Is this the case?

If the answer is affirmative, then I know where I have to move `c.vim` into, and that I have to create a `cpp.vim` file beside that containing only the second line from the `cpp.vim` which is above.

- As a side question, where should I put the other two options, which are not indentation specific? What is their most appropriate location?

Comment: I didn't read all the details, but maybe try `setlocal` instead of `set`?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, without moving the files, I observe the same behavior even when I use `setlocal` (in both the `c.vim` and `cpp.vim` files). On the other hand many files in `/usr/share/vim/vim82/ftplugin/` and use `setlocal`, so doing this change is probably good for some other good reason.

Comment: Yeah, `setlocal` keeps the change local to that buffer (relevant if you have many buffers with different filetypes!). For personal stuff, `after` is also a good way to be sure your settings take effect no matter what

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt look into the standard Vim runtime files.

`ts sts et sw` should be set by `after/ftplugin`.

`sta` is basically no-op, as you have `&sw == &sts` anyway.

`si ai` are basically no-op as you have `&cindent` on. And also, in general, there's nothing in setting `ai si` on if you have any meaningful `indent/xyz.vim`.

`cino` should probably be set by `after/indent`, but in this case I'd rather use `after/ftplugin` to get rid of `after/indent` completely (the standard `indent/c.vim` doesn't set any `cino` values, so it should be okay).

Comment: Wow, Matt, if you use non-short names for options, the readability of your answer improves a hundered times.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, perhaps you might want to store these settings in a Vim script in the `indent/` directory, though the distinction might not be very clear on which settings belong to `indent/` and which ones belong to `plugin/`.

In practical terms, it mostly matters if you only enable filetype plug-ins but not indent (`:filetype plugin on`) or indent plug-ins only but not filetype plug-ins (`:filetype indent on`).

There might be some issues regarding the order in which plug-ins get loaded (I believe scripts from `ftplugin/` are loaded before those from `indent/`, though this might depend on whether you call `filetype plugin indent on` in a single command or use separate commands to enable each kind), but in most cases this will only matter if you're trying to override something from the Vim runtime files.

It's actually debatable whether the specific settings you have belong in `indent/` or `ftplugin/` though. Settings such as `'autoindent'` and `'smartindent'` typically would belong in `indent/`, but in this case (C and C++ file types) they're actually not getting into effect, since the `indent/c.vim` from Vim runtimes enables `'cindent'`, which supercedes these two others.

---

Regardless, one thing you should definitely do is use `setlocal` instead of `set` in these files. You definitely want to affect the current buffer only and not change globals when a C or C++ file is opened.

You might also want to look into `:help undo_ftplugin` and `:help undo_indent`, which can be relevant if you switch file types once a file is already opened. (This is a rare operation, but you might want to implement that for completeness.)

See examples under `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/` and `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/` to get inspiration on those.